# How to start my first TDD project?

Tags: django, tdd

I was given a task to create a project on Django. It is pretty much simple and straightforward, but it's my first task on Django and TDD driven, that is why it has difficulties for me. I have read a lot about TDD on wiki and Django portal, but still do not know how to start.

Simplified models:

- Skill

  1. Description
- Student

  1. Description
  2. Skills
- Project

  1. Task
  2. Description
  3. Students

I need to show information about projects, students and skills. Skills should be like tags: after click show students with that skill. Please help me to start to write my first tests: which unit test should be the first, which questions should I ask myself to create further tests, how small should they be, and so on.

Comment: I did not want my question to look so, but stackoverflow made me to put ``. There were just lists. Please help to fix.

Comment: Like that, you mean? And your question is way too broad for SO, but consider searching for *"obey the testing goat"*...

Comment: @jonrshape I just inserted HTML tags, but forum made me to put it like computer code and did not allow just to show them. sorry if I did something wrong.

Comment: In the future, see http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help. If you click Edit, you can see what I did to make it look as it does now.

Answer (score -1):

I'd start by doing the [django tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/intro/tutorial01/) and then apply the lessons learnt to your project above.

That will give you the starting blocks for the models, and in the final part, an introduction to TDD.

Comment: Not sure why this is downvoted. The question is about starting to unit test with Django. The Django docs have a section in the tutorial about exactly that, which provides a basic intro to the topic ...